# Executing html function in Django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have one `django template` which has one button. All i want is that when i click this button it will include another template and show the contents.

```
<button data-toggle="modal" id="myClickButton" href="#dbModal" type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right custom" >Bookmark</button>
```

The above is my button and it is linked with a modal. In the modal, I am saving a dictionary in a file using a `Django template tag`. So i am including the new `html` with arguments like below.

```
 {% include "app/return_info.html"  with "dict" "String"}
```

I tried several methods but Django runs this `include` command without waiting for button and when i click the button, nothing happened. Modal is displayed but no data is saved.

Comment: yes because you cannot do it like that. on refresh the include will run, if you have to do this, you need to append the data to the modal using jquery

Comment: I can't put this `include` in a function, inside that template and then execute that function only when button is clicked?

Comment: yes inside a js, which will append it to the modal using jquery

Comment: okay let say, i made one `.js` file in `static/app` folder and defined one function in it which will save the data to file and show me the modal that data is saved. Can i pass the data with arguments to this `.js` file from the `django template`?

Comment: it will be better if you use ajax for sending and receiving the data

Comment: if you have time, can you please share any link from where i study about it or write small example? it will be nice. Totally new to Ajax, js, jquery...all of these.

Comment: "ajax to load data to a modal using jquery" search this, and you will find a lot of links where you can find your ans, hope it helps